# Error when using ismatch() function with regex in Julia

Tags: regex, function, julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to do a very simple program to find matches with ismatch() function in Julia. Suppose my pattern is

```
e_pat = r".+@.+"
```

Then I make a list called input with some random elements:

```
input= ["pipo@gmail.com", 23, "trapo", "holi@gmail.com"]
```

Now I want to identify how many matches exist and then print them using e_pat as reference:

```
for i in input
    println(ismatch(e_pat, i)) && println(i)
end
```

With that code I just get "true" and the error displayed below:

```
true

TypeError: non-boolean (Void) used in boolean context

Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at ./In[27]:4 [inlined]
 [2] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
 [3] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

What can I do in order to get the following?

```
"pipo@gmail.com"
"holi@gmail.com"
```

I read ismatch() documentation but found nothing useful. 
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Maybe because 23 is int and not a string.

Comment: Got same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that while this expression **returns** `true`:

```rb
julia> @show ismatch(e_pat, "pipo@gmail.com");
ismatch(e_pat,"pipo@gmail.com") = true
```

Using `println`, just prints `true` but **returns** `nothing`:

```rb
julia> @show println(ismatch(e_pat, "pipo@gmail.com"));
true
println(ismatch(e_pat,"pipo@gmail.com")) = nothing
```

Which is of type `Void`:

```rb
julia> typeof(nothing)
Void
```

And the error is telling you that you cant use an object of type `Void` in a *boolean* context (`nothing`) is just an instance of `Void` treated like a *singleton* in Julia:

```rb
julia> nothing && true
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Void) used in boolean context
```

After fixing that also notice that this is also another error:

```rb
julia> @show ismatch(e_pat, 42);
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ismatch(::Regex, ::Int32)
Closest candidates are:
  ismatch(::Regex, ::SubString{T<:AbstractString}) at regex.jl:151
  ismatch(::Regex, ::SubString{T<:AbstractString}, ::Integer) at regex.jl:151
  ismatch(::Regex, ::AbstractString) at regex.jl:145
  ...
```

This is telling you that `ismatch` has no such method, you can't use it with a combination of arguments of types: `(Regex, Int)`.

You could do something like this instead to make sure all the objects are `String`s:

```rb
julia> input = string.(["pipo@gmail.com", 23, "trapo", "holi@gmail.com"])
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "pipo@gmail.com"
 "23"            
 "trapo"         
 "holi@gmail.com"
```

Finally, you could use the macro `@show` (which prints an expression and its result and finally **returns** the result) instead of the `println` function (which prints the result and **returns** `nothing`, to debug whats going on:

```rb
julia> for i in input
           @show(ismatch(e_pat, i)) && println(i)
       end
ismatch(e_pat,i) = true
pipo@gmail.com
ismatch(e_pat,i) = false
ismatch(e_pat,i) = false
ismatch(e_pat,i) = true
holi@gmail.com
```

So in order to print your expected result just remove the left hand side `println`:

```rb
julia> for i in input
           ismatch(e_pat, i) && println(i)
       end
pipo@gmail.com
holi@gmail.com
```

If you want to store them instead of printing them you could us an array comprehension instead:

```rb
julia> result = [str for str in input if ismatch(e_pat, str)]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "pipo@gmail.com"
 "holi@gmail.com"
```

Or an indexing expression like this one:

```rb
julia> ismatch.(e_pat, input)       
4-element BitArray{1}:              
  true                              
 false                              
 false                              
  true                              

julia> result = input[ismatch.(e_pat, input)]
2-element Array{String,1}:          
 "pipo@gmail.com"                   
 "holi@gmail.com"
```

That way you could print them later without having to repeat the computation:

```rb
julia> println.(result)
pipo@gmail.com
holi@gmail.com
```

Comment: That was pretty useful. Thank you! Just one more question: How can I  convert raw text into string? For example, using same list [pipo@gmail.com, 23, trapo, holi@gmail.com] but without " " strings with @. I'm asking this because I got an error when trying string.([pipo@gmail.com, 23, trapo, holi@gmail.com]). I know @ is for macros in Julia but I want to know if there's nothing I can do about it (maybe @ is a restricted symbol, for example). Thanks again!

Comment: Which version of Julia are you using @AlejandroCarrera?

Comment: `@` symbol is for macros, `23` is an `Int` literal but `pipo@gmail.com` without quotes is an error, that is **not** a literal of any kind, you need to enclose it with quotes so it becomes a string literal. If you have more specific doubts please create a new question about that.

Comment: [Literal (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming))

Comment: I'm on 0.6.2 version. Thank you for your help and your advice!